# Every Time when I use the Number() function so i got an error

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make a simple adding calculator on node.js and express.js that can add only two number but when I use the number function of JS that convert strings to a number so I got the error is:

```
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 4
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:242:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:233:8)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:692:10)
    at ServerResponse.send
```

My CODE IS :

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.post("/", function(req, res){
    var a = Number(req.body.num1);
    var b = Number(req.body.num2);
    var result = a + b;
    res.send(result);
})
app.listen("3000", function(){
    console.log("The App is on port 3000")
})
```

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, if you pass number as first parameter to `send` method, it takes it as status code, and **4** is not valid HTTP status code and that's why the error.

Just change you code to send `json` in response and it will work:

```
res.send({sum:result})
```

Or else if you need number in response you can do like this also:

```
res.send(200,result)
```

Here 200 is success HTTP status code

Answer (score 1):

according to the express's api [doc](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res).

> res.send([body]) Sends the HTTP response.
>
> The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an
>   Array.

So you set a Number to send() may be not work.